# Flutter Search Widget Exception: Null is not supported?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

So im trying to make a search widget, using dio for http client, rxdart for api stream, and i get this error (which is not spesific enough for 'me') while typing a search term (and actually from debug console information it has get the data information from api):

```
I/flutter (11739): Response Text:

I/flutter (11739): {"status":"ok","totalResults":346239,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"wired","name":"Wired"},"author":"Adam Rogers","title":"The Raging Evolutionary War Between Humans and Covid-19","description":"Fighting the pandemic isn’t only about vaccines and drugs. It’s about understanding how viruses mutate and change inside us, and among us.","url":"https://www.wired.com/story/the-raging-evolutionary-war-between-humans-and-covid-19/","urlToImage":"https://media.wired.com/photos/60395f5a490220e41e906b90/191:100/w_1280,c_limit/Science_covidevolution_1257547744.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-03-01T12:00:00Z","content":"The race is on. Vaccines against the virus that causes Covid-19 are needling into shoulders around the world, the tip-of-the-hypodermic spear of a year-long scientific triumph. But that protean virus… [+4050 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"engadget","name":"Engadget"},"author":"Mariella Moon","title":"LG begins selling its latest Gram laptops in the US","description":"LG has revealed the prices and US availability
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Exception: Null is not supported
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<SearchState>                                                lib\…\component\search_screen_v2.dart:136
```

here is the codes :
model.dart

```
class Artikel {
  final Sumber sumber;
  final String penulis;
  final String judul;
  final String deskripsi;
  final String url;
  final String img;
  final String date;
  final String content;

  Artikel(this.sumber, this.penulis, this.judul, this.deskripsi, this.url,
      this.img, this.date, this.content);

  Artikel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : sumber = Sumber.fromJson(json["source"]),
        penulis = json["author"],
        judul = json["title"],
        deskripsi = json["description"],
        url = json["url"],
        img = json["urlToImage"],
        date = json["publishedAt"],
        content = json["content"];
}

class ArtikelResponseV3 {
  final List<Artikel> items;

  ArtikelResponseV3(this.items);

  factory ArtikelResponseV3.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    final items = (json as List)
        .cast<Map<String, Object>>()
        .map((Map<String, Object> item) {
      return Artikel.fromJson(item);
    }).toList();

    return ArtikelResponseV3(items);
  }

  bool get isPopulated => items.isNotEmpty;

  bool get isEmpty => items.isEmpty;
}
```

api_repository.dart

```
Future<ApiResult<ArtikelResponseV3>> getSearch2(String value) async {
var params = {"apiKey": _apiKey, "q": value, "sortBy": "relevancy"};

try {
  Response response = await dioClientEverything.get(_everythingUrl,
      queryParameters: params);
  List<Artikel> artikelList = ArtikelResponseV3.fromJson(response).items;
  return ApiResult.success(data: ArtikelResponseV3.fromJson(response.data));
} catch (e) {
  return ApiResult.failure(error: NetworkExceptions.getDioException(e));
}
```

bloc_repository

```
class GetSearchV2Bloc {
  final Sink<String> onTextChanged;
  final Stream<SearchState> state;

  factory GetSearchV2Bloc(ApiRepository api) {
    // ignore: close_sinks
    final onTextChanged = PublishSubject<String>();

    final state = onTextChanged
        .distinct()
        .debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 250))
        .switchMap<SearchState>((String term) => _search(term, api))
        .startWith(SearchNoTerm());

    return GetSearchV2Bloc._(onTextChanged, state);
  }

  GetSearchV2Bloc._(this.onTextChanged, this.state);

  void dispose() {
    onTextChanged.close();
  }

  static Stream<SearchState> _search(String term, ApiRepository api) => term
          .isEmpty
      ? Stream.value(SearchNoTerm())
      : Rx.fromCallable(() => api.getSearch2(term)).map((result) => result.when(
            success: (ArtikelResponseV3 data) {
              SearchPopulated(data);
            },
            failure: (NetworkExceptions error) {
              SearchError(error);
            },
          )
              ? SearchEmpty()
              : SearchLoading());
}
```

related search_screen code:

````
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  child: StreamBuilder<SearchState>(
                      stream: bloc.state,
                      initialData: SearchNoTerm(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<SearchState> snapshot) {
                        final state = snapshot.data;
                        if (state is SearchNoTerm) {
                          return SearchIntro();
                        } else if (state is SearchEmpty) {
                          return EmptyWidget();
                        } else if (state is SearchLoading) {
                          return LoadingWidget();
                        } else if (state is SearchError) {
                          return SearchErrorWidget();
                        } else if (state is SearchPopulated) {
                          return _buildSourceNewsWidget(state.result);
                        }

                        throw Exception(
                            '${state.runtimeType} is not supported');
                        // return _buildChild(state);
                      })))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSourceNewsWidget(ArtikelResponseV3 artikel) {
    List<Artikel> data = artikel.items;
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => DetailBerita(
                            artikel: data[index],
                          )));
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200], width: 1.0),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              height: 150,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 3 / 5,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(data[index].judul,```
````

Comment: It looks like you are giving a widget a null value. you may try printing every value before passing it to the widget (not the all the response).

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh so i have to change my model response or the rxdart method?

Comment: just print the data before passing it to the widget tree

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh i've tried, i put print() after switchMap(), but it still "null is not supported" ??

Comment: Try adding another if statement in `AnimatedSwitcher`, add if (state == null)